# Angular 1.x Ng-If statement works with && but not ||, why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Have an ng-if link to show a button:

```
<button ng-if="myOwnProfile == false || AreWeFriends == false" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="connect($id)">connect</button>
```

I want it to show if either is false; however with this code myOwnProfile never gets evaluated and does not work. What is supposed to happen (and this works when I have each statement by itself) is a button disappears if the user is viewing their own profile and is shown if the user isn't 'friends' with someone.

Statements work fine on their own but when I use an ||, it refuses to work :(
When I use an "&&" statement, they do evaluate correctly; however, why would this logic work when using an "and"? I want to do an either/or.

Comment: Use the `!` (negation) operator instead of `== false`!

Comment: Or use the `===` (identity) operator if you require the type to be a boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the condition for not show: ownprofile and are friend

so the condition for show: not ownprofile or friends

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myOwnProfile = true;
  $scope.AreWeFriends = true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl"><button ng-if="myOwnProfile == false || AreWeFriends == true" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="connect($id)">connect</button>
  <button ng-click="myOwnProfile = !myOwnProfile">My Own Profile</button>
  <button ng-click="AreWeFriends = !AreWeFriends">AreWeFriends</button>

  <div>
    myOwnProfile: {{ myOwnProfile }} <br> AreWeFriends: {{ AreWeFriends }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, the button isn't actually running. I hide it if a profile is loaded that is either a) the user's own profile or b) one they are already connected to.
So - I have checks in the controller which set $scope.myOwnProfile to true or AreWeFriends to true if they checks out in an if statement.

So - It's confusing to me why it appears with the ==. :)

Comment: @nashvilleCoder the buttons in the code snippet is only for test. I think this is not about the || statement, you have to look into your condition for when should the button display.

Comment: Thank you. I've got a bit confused at the logic, I realized I never set the fact that I would never be a friend of myself (on my own profile), so it was always displaying when I viewed a profile... oops. That's why the && works... :)

Thank you for the help.

Comment: @nashvilleCoder glad for you have found the problem.